# Line 8 - error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Queue:maxQue'

Tags: c++, c++11, queue

I am attempting to implement a simple queue array program in C++ but I've ran into these errors.

*Line 8 - error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Queue:maxQue'*

*Line 12 - error: from this location*

*Line 55 - 'intQueue' was not declared in this scope*

Here is my private members in my class definition:

```
class Queue
{
private:
    int maxQue = 5;
    int length;
    int beginning;
    int rear;
    int intQueue[maxQue];
```

This is part of the function where I got the error on line 55.

```
void Queue::enqueue(int x, bool checkFull)
{
if(!checkFull)
{
    if(beginning == -1)
        beginning = 0;
    rear = (rear + 1) % maxQue;
    length++;
    intQueue[rear] = x;

}
```

Please help if you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not use 'maxQue' (an instance variable) to specify the size of compile time known array size.

You should at least specify it as constexpr and static

```
class Queue
{
private:
    constexpr static int maxQue = 5;
...
}
```

Comment: Ok this helped. Thank you!